# TexMaker opens the tex file in a different path

Tags: latex

I am not sure if I called the problem correctly. I have Mixtex and TexMaker (the latest versions) installed on my PC with ubuntu 20.04. I want to run tex files on my usb drive. But when I open a tex file in a usb by TexMaker, a copy of this tex file is created in a file in /run/user/1000/doc, and texmaker actually opens this copied one (not the one in my usb drive). So the output is created in this file, not in the usb drive.

This problem does not occur for any tex file in any place of the hard disc of my computer (Desktop, Documents, ...)

This problem does not occur for any other type of files in my usb (ods, ...).

This problem does not occur with other Latex editors (I installed other editors, and they really opened the file on the usb and created the output there).

I hadn't this problem two days ago, I didn't change any setting of my usb and TexMaker.

I want to use TexMaker (it is the simplest and fastest editor for me). I don't want to copy all files to drive of the computer, work on them and then copy back to usb, I need to work on usb.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `/run/user/1000/doc` is probably just the USB drive's *gvfs mount point*. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The output files (pdf, ps,...) are not created in the usb folder which contains the tex file. They are created in the folder in /run/user/1000/doc.